# Python - "client_id" is missing. How to solve?

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api, django-allauth

I've been playing with the LinkedIn api (OAuth 2) and I've found an example to help test it. I've followed the tutorial to the letter, but for some reason when I provide my full redirect URL (as requested in the code), I get the error: `(invalid_request) A required parameter "client_id" is missing`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but if anyone has any idea, I appreciate the feedback.

Upon searching for a solution, I've found another person struggling with this: ["client_id" is missing when authenticate with LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124186/client-id-is-missing-when-authenticate-with-linkedin/55089204#55089204)

Here's the code from the example:

`Linkedin.py`

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import linkedin_compliance_fix

# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = SECRET
client_secret = SECRET

# OAuth endpoints given in the LinkedIn API documentation
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'

linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000')
linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(linkedin)

# Redirect user to LinkedIn for authorization
authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
print ('Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')

# Fetch the access token
linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,authorization_response=redirect_response)

# Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
r = linkedin.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~')
print (r.content)
```

Link to example: https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/linkedin.html

Additional Note: The tutorial I used didn't have a date on it. I can only assume the links used in the API tutorial are correct and up to date.

Answer (score 2):

This one is a little old but I thought I'd share some additional changes that need to be made to the LinkedIn example from the oauth requests documentation site.

Along with the updated links, it would seem that LinkedIn is expecting the `client_id` in the body of the request when trading the verifier code for a a token. I'm not exactly sure where or when it gets left behind but after drilling down in oauth-request source code I found that the `fetch` method has an argument which forces the `client_id` to be included in the request body (`include_client_id`) adding it to the fetch method should make the example work.

```
linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,
                     authorization_response=redirect_response,
                     include_client_id=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `URLs`, I wrote a similar program and it worked perfectly for me:

```py
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import linkedin_compliance_fix


# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = '<the client id you get from linkedin>'
client_secret = '<the client secret you get from linkedin>'
redirect_url = '<authorized redirect URL from LinkedIn config>'

# OAuth endpoints given in the LinkedIn API documentation (you can check for the latest updates)
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'

# Authorized Redirect URL (from LinkedIn configuration)
linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_url)
linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(linkedin)

# Redirect user to LinkedIn for authorization
authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
print('Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')

# Fetch the access token
linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,
                     authorization_response=redirect_response)

# Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
r = linkedin.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~')
print(r.content)
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the reason for your issue, you are using an older version of LinkedIn's authentication URLs. From LinkedIn's OAuth documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/consumer/context) your authorziation_base_url should be

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization